# Load/Deserialize faster Json data to C# object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In my code I use Newtonsoft.Json :

```
MyCSharpTargetClass foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCSharpTargetClass>(json_string);
```

The content of the json_string is constant (loaded from a file that never changes).

The functionality is fine but the deserializing process is slow at execution.

My question: is there a way to pre-calculate the object, or to put it in a constant*, or whatever to speed up the execution ?

Note: Actually I didn't manage to put it a constant the result of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<...>(), but I'm new to C#, so I should have missed something.

Thanks for your help

**[EDIT] Solution : Force the Newtonsoft assembly to be loaded at the start of the application.**

Comment: What is your project type? Winforms? Web? Console?

Comment: _"the deserializing process is slow at execution"_ - how certain are you of that and how did you determine it? Is the string _that_ big? Also, why do you read it again and again to notice if it changed? If it's a big file, why can't you just read the relevant part? Why can't you watch for events to the file instead?

Comment: @msd : Application UWP (mainly for windows 10 mobile)

Comment: @CodeCaster : The json file is read only once. It is not big (about 100 small lines). On desktop, the process duration is barely noticeable; but on my windows 10 mobile Nokia 1520, there is a big difference (about 1.5s) between full constant (hardcoded) and the deserializing operation (even if the json string itself is in constant). That's how a guess the root of the slowing down.

Comment: Is that delay only the first time, or does it occur every time?

Comment: @CodeCaster : Only the first time (after it's fast). Hum... I should investigate this.

Comment: That would be the loading of the Newtonsoft assembly.

Answer (score 1):

There's actualy not a lot of thinks you can do to speed this up.

1. Using ignore attribute, so this fields will not be added. Use this for some properties or calcualatable properties/fields, which can be recalculated later.
   Hope this link helps :

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx
2. Using threads to read/write your objects, if you can customize your data into many files and serialize/deserialize in threads.
3. Deserialization JSON algorithms requires to read whole file about 3 times.
   For better perfomance you can use **YAML**. Simple as XML/JSON, but with much better perfomance, since it reads file only 1 time.
4. Using shorter `DataMember` names to fields 
   `[DataMember(Name = "id")]
   public int MyObjectForSomethink{get;set;}`

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support number 3? I've had no issues in the past reading an entire JSON file incrementally in a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

You do it the same way you would any other object: make it a `private` member variable, whose value is computed exactly once:

```
private static readonly MyCSharpTargetClass foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCSharpTargetClass>(json_string);
```

Or do it in the constructor:

```
private readonly MyCSharpTargetClass foo;

public MyObject()
{
    foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCSharpTargetClass>(json_string);
}
```

That way the work to deserialize the string is done exactly once.